# No text from epslatex terminal in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to use the epslatex terminal in gnuplot, using the example code [from this site](http://www.gnuplotting.org/code/terminal_epslatex.gnu).

Copying and pasting this example and running the gnuplot script produces the following output:
[image: naked plot]

No labels!  This happens under Ubuntu 11.10 using gnuplot 4.4.4 and under Arch using gnuplot 4.6.0.

Looking at the output `.tex` file it seems that the label text is there in the file, but might be put outside the plot area:

```
\begin{picture}(5040.00,3772.00)%
  \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
    \csname LTb\endcsname%
    \put(860,1122){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$-1$}}%
    \put(860,2086){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$0$}}%
    \put(860,3049){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$1$}}%
    \put(980,440){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-2\pi$}}%
    \put(1875,440){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-\pi$}}%
    \put(2770,440){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
    \put(3665,440){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$\pi$}}%
    \put(4560,440){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$2\pi$}}%
    \put(160,2085){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$y$}}}%
    \put(2770,140){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$x$}}%
  }%  
  \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
    \csname LTb\endcsname%
    \put(3725,3238){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$\sin(x)$}}%
  }%  
  \gplbacktext
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics{terminal_epslatex-inc}}%
  \gplfronttext
\end{picture}
```

Any ideas as to why there would be no label text visible here?

Comment: The linked example works for me. Indeed, I get other positions for the label with gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3 on OpenSuse 12.1. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41227811/terminal_epslatex.tex) is my tex file. Don't know why you get a faulty tex file, though... Are there any gnuplot configuration files?

Comment: Try to delete the line `\gplfronttext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEBKAC.  I thought the generated .eps file was supposed to be the final (standalone) output, but it is necessary to run `pdflatex` on the generated .tex file to properly render the plot with labels.